# Make a frequency table with categories in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to make an easy frequency table in Python, but I can't find the answer. My data contains numbers from 0 to 10, for example:

> 1,2,3,4,5,5,5,8,8,8,0,9,10,2,2,10,10,7,7,7,7,9.

I want to make a frequency table with the counts and percentiles (zero excluded!) of these values turned into 3 categories:

> Category 1 : lower than 5,5
>   Category 2 : Between 5,5 and 8
>   Category 3 : 8 or higher

My output then needs to be:

> Category 1 : frequency 9/ 43%
>   Category 2 : frequency 4/19%
>   Category 3 : frequency 8/38%

How do I do this in Python?

Comment: As far as I understand, you are trying to somehow create the so-called bins. Maybe numpy can do the job for you.See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html . Another way would be to create a dataframe using pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated version that will work for your use-case:

```
dd = {"cat_1":0, "cat_2":0, "cat_3":0}
values = [1,2,3,4,5,5,5,8,8,8,0,9,10,2,2,10,10,7,7,7,7,9]
for value in values:
    if value > 0 and value < 5.5:
        dd["cat_1"] += 1
    elif value >= 5.5 and value < 8:
        dd["cat_2"] += 1
    elif value >= 8:
        dd["cat_3"] += 1

print(f"Category 1 : frequency {dd['cat_1']}/{(dd['cat_1']/(len(values)-values.count(0)))*100}")
print(f"Category 2 : frequency {dd['cat_2']}/{(dd['cat_2']/(len(values)-values.count(0)))*100}")
print(f"Category 3 : frequency {dd['cat_3']}/{(dd['cat_3']/(len(values)-values.count(0)))*100}")
```

Comment: This looks good. But how do I exclude the zeros in the data? The part in the for-loop is clear (if value >0 and value < 5.5), but how do I exclude them in the percentiles?

Comment: Oh, so you want them to be included in the frequencies but not in the percentiles?

Comment: @marita Finally understood how you meant. See my updated answer!